# How does the Android Market (Play Store) "push" installs to my phone?

Tags: android, web-services, google-play

I've noticed a trend by which vendors will allow you to install apps/music/books, etc to your registered device while you're initiating the request through a web interface.

An example of this would be the Google Play store. When signed into the same account as my Android phone, I can click 'Install' on an app and in a few seconds, see that my phone is installing the app.

Amazon's Kindle does something similar.

**My Question**

What is the mechanism used to do this? Are the devices constantly polling in the background for these type of updates or is there some way to push these sort of updates without the device needing to poll?

Comment: `I've noticed a trend` hihi ... sorry, but this is already standard, not a trend :) - official doc: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: @WarrenFaith you should post that as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google developed his version of push to device called Google Cloud Messaging (renamed from C2DM).

You can get the basics here: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

For general knowledge about the technology, read the wikipedia article @Aerilys posted.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're searching about the push concept.
Wikipedia can provide you more detais :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology